# PHP iterating through a simple comma separated list

Tags: php

I have a string which can be

```
$string = "value.";
```

OR

```
$string = "value1, value2.";
```

I want to iterate through this string getting each item which are -> `value` (in first example) and -> `value1` AND `value2` in the second (without the comma or the dot in the end).

I was thinking of;

1. Replace the dot in the end.
2. Check if there is any comma.
3. If there is comma, split-explode using ", " and iterate through.
4. If not, only one item so just use it.

Is this the right way of doing it?

I am new to PHP and trying to learn best practices and best ways of solving the issues.

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't replace I would just trim the last character from the string. I think you can explode regardless, and if there is no comma it will just have 1 value. Otherwise, your strategy is the one I would take.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're absolutely right, you could do it like this:

```
$string = 'foo, bar, baz.';
$string = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $string); //Remove dot at end if exists
$array = explode(', ', $string); //split string into array seperated by ', '
foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
{
    echo $value . PHP_EOL; //print value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered, but, you could do this with one command:

```
$input = "foo, bar, baz., shibby, poop.";

//-- handles it all in one pass
$output = preg_split('/[\.,\s]/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//-- just output
array_walk($output, function(&$item, $idx) {
    echo $idx . ': ' . $item . PHP_EOL;
});
```

If you're expecting spaces in your values, however, this will split them up too. I just added `\s` to the regex to trim the elements. If you expect spaces in values, then omit the `\s` in the regex and `trim()` the elements later.

Or, this regex will produce the same: `/(\.\s?|,\s?)/`

```
$input = "foo, bar, baz., shibby, poop. foo bar";

//-- handles it all in one pass
$output = preg_split('/(\.\s?|,\s?)/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//-- just output
array_walk($output, function(&$item, $idx) {
    echo $idx . ': ' . $item . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Produces

```
0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
3: shibby
4: poop
5: foo bar
```

**The Regex: explained**

The original regex simply split on single characters in the string as denoted by the `[` and `]`. Thus, `/[\.,\s]/` matches on period, comma, AND space characters in the string. After thinking about it, this is probably not what you want but close.

The updated regex is a little different and splits on two different scenarios. `\.\s?` says: split on the period and/or preiod+space. The `?` makes the preceding optional (I believe 0 or 1). Same with the `,\s?`. Match on comma and/or comma+space. This accounts for all the scenarios. Using grouping (`(...)`) instead of character ranges allows for this. The pipe `|` in the middle means OR so, the complete regex means: match on period and/or period+space OR comma and/or comma+space.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "value 1, value2";
$string = trim($string, ".");

$split = explode(",", $string);
print_r($split);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use following code:

```
$string = "value1, value2.";
$arr = explode(', ', trim($string, '.'));
print_r($arr);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do 2 and 4. If there is no comma then it will split to an array of one element.

Answer (score 1):

When you explode, and there is no delimiter you have requested, the result at index 0 is the entire string.

```
<?php
$string = "test, test2., test3, test4";
print_r( explode(',', $string) );
//Array
//(
//    [0] => test
//    [1] =>  test2.
//    [2] =>  test3
//    [3] =>  test4
//)

$string = "test test2. test3 test4";
print_r( explode(',', $string) );
//Array
//(
//    [0] => test test2. test3 test4
//)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$arr="a,b,c";
$variableAry=explode(",",$arr); 
foreach($variableAry as $var)
{
 echo"<input type='text' value=".$var." ><br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers that fabricate their own input string (despite the OP providing two -- neither of which yours represents) and do not attempt to solve the OP's issue ...four years after higher-quality answers have been posted are of no use to the OP or researchers.