# Displaying orders in custom HTML transactional emails

Tags: php, woocommerce, html-email, transactional-email

So I have this problem.
I'm using WooCommerce and Campaign Monitor for transactional emails. I have made a custom HTML template for order confirmation. I also use Zapier for sending those email, but when there is more than one position in the order, the products ale being displayed separated by comma, not in tables.

| Product | Desc. | Quant. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First, second, third | desc1, desc2, desc3 | 1,4,10. |

instead of

| Products | Description. | Quant. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | desc1 | 1 |
| Second | desc2 | 4 |
| Thrid | desc3 | 10 |

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: So I have this problem. I'm using WooCommerce and Campaign Monitor for transactional emails.  I understand,   WooCommerce and Campaign Monitor are problematic.

Comment: It would help to have the code you have currently. I gather you would need a loop to create a new row for each item - something like this perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839147/php-iterating-through-a-simple-comma-separated-list

Comment: The code is pure HTML, therefore, how to create loop that puts each item in a new row?

Comment: You need to use PHP, or alternatively, use an extension that does this for you

Comment: Cheers. Ended up modifing woocommerce email files. Been just wondering if it could be done via CM.